# Взятие данных переменной из XML Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Нужно взять данные в переменную из string.xml , но при работе кода берется код символа
Как правильно обратиться к данным в xml файле?

```
when(z) {
                1 -> {
                    textzad.setImageResource(R.drawable.zad1_1)
                    otvet = R.string.zad1_1_otvet.toString()
                }
                2 -> {
                    textzad.setImageResource(R.drawable.zad1_2)
                    otvet = R.string.zad1_2_otvet.toString()
                }
                3 -> {
                    textzad.setImageResource(R.drawable.zad1_3)
                    otvet = R.string.zad1_3_otvet.toString()
                }
                4 -> {
                    textzad.setImageResource(R.drawable.zad1_4)
                    otvet = R.string.zad1_4_otvet.toString()
                }
                5 -> {
                    textzad.setImageResource(R.drawable.zad1_5)
                    otvet = R.string.zad1_5_otvet.toString()
                }
            }
```

Comment: Не путайте сами ресурсы c их идентификаторами. Абсолютно все ресурсы в Андроид, независимо от типа, имеют идентификаторы типа `int`.

Answer (score 2):

В любом месте где есть `Context` есть метод:

```
 /**
 * Returns a localized string from the application's package's
 * default string table.
 *
 * @param resId Resource id for the string
 * @return The string data associated with the resource, stripped of styled
 *         text information.
 */

@NonNull
public final String getString(@StringRes int resId) {
    return getResources().getString(resId);
}
```

Выглядит это примерно так:

**Activity**

```
String text = getString(R.string.zad1_4_otvet);
```

**Fragment**

```
String text = requiareContext().getString(R.string.zad1_4_otvet);
```